# PHPExcel Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pdo, export

I'm trying to export a mysql query table to an excel file. I have it working on another page on my site however it seems to be having trouble with this particular query.
I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 
Unknown column 'u2.confirmed_cash' in 'field list' in 
/home2/jtdsdevc/public_html  /rbk/usage-v3/inc/excel-exporter
/MySqlExcelBuilder.class.php on line 130
```

This is my code.

```
// Setup the SQL Statements
$sql_statement = getReport($idLeague, $idTeam);

function getReport($idLeague, $idTeam){
global $connect;

$sql = "
    SELECT idPlayer AS id,
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', location, name) FROM `team` WHERE `team`.id = u.idTeam) AS team,
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) FROM `player` WHERE `player`.id = u.idPlayer) AS name, 
    (SELECT u2.confirmed_cash FROM `usage` u2 WHERE u.idPlayer = u2.idPlayer ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS total_cash, 
    (SELECT u2.confirmed_product FROM `usage` u2 WHERE u.idPlayer = u2.idPlayer ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS total_product, 
    max(date) AS last_entry 
    FROM `usage` u INNER JOIN `team` t ON u.idTeam =t.id INNER JOIN `league` l ON t.idLeague =l.id WHERE (t.idleague =".$idLeague." or l.pID =".$idLeague." ) 
    ";

return $sql;
}

// Add the SQL statements to the spread sheet
$mysql_xls->add_page('Report',$sql_statement);

// Get the spreadsheet after the SQL statements are built...
$phpExcel = $mysql_xls->getExcel(); // This needs to come after all the pages have been added.
....
```

That's where the error happens. The exact line in the MySqlExcelBuilder.class.php file is:

```
if ($sh = $this->pdo->query($sql))
```

The `$sql` variable above comes out to be

```
SELECT idPlayer AS id, 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', location, name) FROM `team` WHERE `team`.id = u.idTeam) AS team, 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) FROM `player` WHERE `player`.id = u.idPlayer) AS name, 
(SELECT u2.confirmed_cash FROM `usage` u2 WHERE u.idPlayer = u2.idPlayer ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS total_cash, 
(SELECT u3.confirmed_product FROM `usage` u3 WHERE u.idPlayer = u3.idPlayer ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS total_product, 
max(date) AS last_entry 
FROM `usage` u 
INNER JOIN `team` t ON u.idTeam =t.id 
INNER JOIN `league` l ON t.idLeague =l.id 
WHERE (t.idleague =1 or l.pID =1 )
```

Edit: It is also worth noting that the query by itself works fine in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: So does the column `usage.confirmed_cash` exist? Not sure if it matters in a `SELECT` list but you are using the alias `u2` for two different queries. Change the second to a different alias.

Comment: I did as you suggested, still no dice. The column does exist in the table, in fact when I copy/paste that query (And replace the variables) into phpMyAdmin, it works just fine!

Comment: Just to clarify for anybody reading this, MySqlExcelBuilder.class.php is not a part of PHPExcel (otherwise I'll be inundated with questiosn from people asking where it is in the PHPExcel library)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know it wasn't. I wasn't the one who implemented it, I'm just in charge of fixing it and it's in the same folder. Good to know though, edited out of my original post.

Comment: The value of the variable in the query is...?

Comment: I just posted the full query that is in the SQL variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! I was calling the wrong database, rookie mistake.